# Python order list based on keys of nested list with dict, nested in a list with dict

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
group = [
    {
        "name": "Group2",
        "memberships": [
            {
                "username": "test1",
                "credits": [
                    {
                        "credits": 1000,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 42,
                        "game_count": 1,
                        "last_game_credits": 10,
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "username": "test2",
                "credits": [
                    {
                        "credits": 1500,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 42,
                        "game_count": 1,
                        "last_game_credits": 0,
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "username": "test",
                "credits": [
                    {
                        "credits": 1000,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 42,
                        "game_count": 1,
                        "last_game_credits": 0,
                    }
                ],
               
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to rank/order a list of Memberships based on multiple fields in the Credits object:

- credits (amount)
- game_count (amount)
- last_game_credits (amount)

Hence, if two players have an equal amount of credits the one with the highest game_count wins. If that is the same the one with the highest last_game_credits wins.

I want the same structure to be returned.

I can rank the memberships list like this:

```
newList = sorted(group[0]['memberships'], key=lambda e: (e['credits'][0]['credits'], e['credits'][0]['game_count'], e['credits'][0]['last_game_credits']), reverse=True)
```

But that just gives me the list of memberships and not the other information.

I need to sort the whole group by gaining access to the Credits keys in 'e' from `group` and not `group[0]['memberships']`.

Comment: So you want to replace the `memberships` element of `group` with a sorted version of the current list in `memberships`?

Comment: @ScottHunter I want to sort the ordering of the member objects under memberships based on the keys in member.credits obj

Comment: Use `group[0]['memberships'].sort()` to modify the list in place.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, yes .sort() works. But I'm trying to do it with sorted() because I need it to transform a Django queryset

Comment: Then assign the result back to the dictionary element: `group[0]['memberships'] = newList`

Comment: @Barmar, I don't know what you mean with this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your restrictions. Why can't you use `.sort()` before you transform it to a queryset?

Comment: The result as shown above is the already returned queryset. Now I just need to sort it

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result of `sorted()` back to the `memberships` element.

```
for g in group:
    g['memberships'] = sorted(g['memberships], key=lambda e: (e['credits'][0]['credits'], e['credits'][0]['game_count'], e['credits'][0]['last_game_credits']), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Barmar. I already tried this but it doesn't work. It sees the .sort as an attribute and I get the following error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: The question says it's a list, not a `QuerySet`.

Comment: Convert it to a list first: `g['memberships'] = list(g['memberships'])`